# Updated and published website - changes not taking effect in search results?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, web-crawlers

**Question Background:**

I've recently updated my website and republished it using Azure. This is fine and the changes have taken effect when I open and view the site from a Google search. This is the old information before the data was changed and re-published.

**The Issue:**

What **hasn't** change though is the title of the site and the summary. The following shows what differs in the results to what is in my sites `title` and `h1` elements where this information is being rendered from.

I have requested Google to re-crawl the site through the use of the webmaster tools.

**Is this delay in the data being changed normal? Is it just a case of waiting for the site to be re-crawled by Google? I deployed the site about 3 hours ago if that helps to determine the answer.**

Comment: It can take weeks or months depending upon previous site performance- freshness, popularity in the SERPs, etc. Search engines are not real-time nor is that even possible- the Internet is so vast that it just plain takes time for changes to appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search engine updates aren't instantaneous.  In fact it can take a couple of weeks or so to be visible.